# Linux: Run a specific command as another user?

Tags: linux, shell, sh, rhel9

I want to be able to allow users to run a specific command as another user, is this possible?

I have a script that reads a remote file through ssh to get a status, something like:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/sh

state=$(ssh -q -i $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa" auto@remote-host "[ -f /path/to/state/file ] && cat /path/to/state/file 2>/dev/null")

printf "${state}"
```

The `auto` user has a key setup so that it can login to the remote machine without a password. I want users to be able to run this script without needing to worry about setting up their own key, for example:

`bob@local-machine$ /path/to/state-check`

So, the `bob` user can run the script as the `auto` user without hassle. I know you can use something like

`su auto -c "/path/to/state-check"`

But that would still require access to the auto user's password or sudo. Is there a way to set up a file that allows bob to run specific commands as auto passwordless? Or should I redesign the tool so that the state files are fetched and stored locally? I'm not really sure of a good way to do this. I'm running this on RHEL 9 machines.

Comment: consider setting auto up as a service on the remote server instead of relying on ssh.

Comment: sudo and su can do this, while sudo can be restricted to Only allow one command

Comment: **1.** Simply remove `auto@` from your command line. `ssh` will use *logname*  as user for connection. **2.** Or use `ssh ... $USER@...`.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to be able to allow users to run a specific command as another user, is this possible?

#### Yes

That is what the `sudo` command is designed for.

Although many novice Linux sysadmins only know and use `sudo` to run commands / elevate or escalate privileges to root and full administrator rights, and many examples only grant unrestricted and unlimited privileges   `sudo` is explicitly designed to [grant restricted privileges](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers) and can also be used to run a single and/or only some specific commands under the UID of a different, non-privileged user.

See also https://serverfault.com/a/639062

Answer (score 0):

Besides `sudo`, mentioned by @HBruijn, you can also use [pkexec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polkit) from [Polkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polkit) (aka Policy Kit). See also: [polkit(8)](https://linux.die.net/man/8/polkit) man page.